# Jenkins credentials in pipeline best practices

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

We have several repositories and each has its own CI pipeline in Jenkins.
In one of the pipelines we checkout the source code by using the following:

```
git branch: 'master',
    credentialsId: 'CREDENTIAL-ID1',
    url: 'GIT-SSH-ADDRESS1'
```

CREDENTIAL-ID1 is a Global credential id and as far as I noticed, it can be used in other pipelines within Jenkins.

As each pipeline owns by a specific group in our team, we don't want CREDENTIAL-ID1 to be visible to any other pipelines.

Is there any solution for this? Does Jenkins have any feature for restricting access to Credential Ids to certain pipelines or users?

What are the best practices in this regard?

Comment: As i have not tested only as comment: You can use the [Folders Plugin](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/folder/) in combination with [Role-Based Access Control Plugin](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/rbac/) to restrict access to The folders, also you can add folder-level credentials, meaning that referenced credential ID will only be valid inside that folder. Together this should allow what you need.